# How to detect textarea or input type="text" editing?

Tags: javascript

I use this snippet to prevent the user from accidentally navigating away from the editing page:

```
var warning = false;
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  if (warning) {
    return '';
  }
}
```

Now I want to set the variable warning to be true if any of the textarea or input type="text" has been modified, I want to use the onkeyup event such as in:

```
document.getElementById('textarea_id').onkeyup = function() {
    warning = true;
}
```

But it's not working. Don't quite want to use jQuery on this. Any insights?

**Update:**

Changed to this:

```
var warning = false;
window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
  if (warning) {
    return 'You have unsaved changes.';
  }
}
document.getElementById('textarea_id').onkeyup = function() {
    warning = true;
}
```

Yet it's still not working.

By the way, it's put in  in the  of the page. There are no javascript anywhere else.

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: Thanks, I put the document.getElementById() part at the end of the page and it's working now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value of the `onbeforeunload` event is only used if it isn't equivalent to `false`.

Change `return '';` to

```
return 'You have unsaved changes.';
```